# Internal resistance and a resistor as a potential divider

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electronics, batteries

Based on the fact that batteries have some kind of internal resistance, if I had a circuit that consisted of a battery and a resistor of some kind would they act like a potential (voltage) divider?

Also does it need to have an output to be classified as a potential (voltage) divider?

Answer (score 1):

The [Thevenin equivalent circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) of a battery is an ideal voltage source $V_B$ in series with a resistor $R_i$ representing the internal resistance of the battery. When you connect the battery to an external resistance $R$, a current $$I=\frac {V_B}{R_i+R}$$ will flow and the voltage drop over the resistance $R$ will be given by the voltage division $$V_R=V_B \frac {R}{R_i+R}$$